# linux process S status but 100% of cpu

Tags: linux

A process is in S status, but the usage of cpu is 100% on linux host.Why?[hk_server S status but 100% of cpu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwlsL.png)

I've tried to test process status, It is acatually in S status.Like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
while :
do
    cat /proc/18938/stat | awk '{print $3}'
done
```

Output:
S
S
S
S
S
S
S
S
S
S .......
No R

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628037/cpu-utilization-high-for-sleeping-processes

Answer (score 1):

It is almost impossible to catch 'R' in action unless you have a process that does something like ->

```
while (1) {
  /* Do Something */
}
```

So I think a better bet would be to monitor 'top' command for a while to see if you can identify culprit(s).

Comment: Thanks.problem solved. It turns out main thread sleep but other thread endless loop. 'top -H' command shows one of threads is R